# CSS and html layout

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I have this html and css layout. I want to make it when reaching tablet with media query and phone to show like in those 2 images. So I have in normal (desktop mode) 4 products all of them in the same line. When the view reaches tablet - 1199 pixels I want those 4 products to be each 2 on a separate line, so 2 lines with 2 products. On the phone mode 768 pixels I want each product to be on its line with the width full like the wrapper.

Here is the code :

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}


/* Header */

.header {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.info {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 285px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: right;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.menu {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/*  */


/* Nav-Bar */

.nav-bar {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 340px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/*  */


/* Product grid */

.product1,
.product2,
.product3 {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 285px;
  height: 320px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.product4 {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 285px;
  height: 320px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
}


/*  */


/* Bottom Part */

.content-area {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 420px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/*  */


/* Footer */

.footer-area {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/*  */


/* Responsive */

@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .product1,
  .product2,
  .product3,
  .product4 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Home View</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/homestyle.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Header -->
  <div class="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <div class="info"></div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="menu"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--  -->

  <!-- NavBar -->
  <div class="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="nav-bar"></div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--  -->

  <!-- Product Grid -->
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="def1">
      <div class="product1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="def2">
      <div class="product2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="def3">
      <div class="product3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="def4">
      <div class="product4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <!--  -->

  <!-- Bottom Part -->
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content-area"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="footer-area"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The CSS[Tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuTHI.jpg) : [image: Phone]
I attached the images needed for the layout. Please help!

Comment: I can't see your images

Comment: https://postimg.org/gallery/iz16jy3g/a2cb7275/ here are the images

Comment: I added the answer for you...

Comment: You have to try to play with Bootstrap. It will help you with all your needs and is super simple! 
Here you go: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 1):

First you add the view port element to Head of the HTML page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Ref. link - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Then Remove fixed width's from `.menu` and `.nav-bar` classes and add as `max-width`.

```
.menu {
    background-color: grey;
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.nav-bar {
    background-color: lightgray;
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 340px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

And also you need to wrap your "Product slots" using "div".
(I used class called "wrapper-inner")

```
<!-- Product Grid -->
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper-inner">
            <div class="def1">
                    <div class="product1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="def2">
                    <div class="product2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="def3">
                    <div class="product3"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="def4">
                    <div class="product4"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--  -->
```

Then after you can add required CSS media queries.

```
    /* Responsive */
    @media all and (max-width: 1199px) {

     .wrapper-inner {
        margin: 0 -20px;
        background: orange;
        padding: 0 20px;
     }

     .def1, .def2, .def3, .def4 {
        width: 50%;
        padding: 20px;
        float: left;
     }

     .product1, .product2, .product3, .product4 {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 0;
     }

    }

    @media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    .def1, .def2, .def3, .def4 {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        float: left;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for you help. For the mobile part is working. But for the tablet mode is not. It shows 4 products one below each other when it should show 2 products in a line and 2 products below.

Comment: It's working fine for me. When view-port size is 1199px, It should be worked.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct in using media queries. In those you can f.e. set the width of your elements like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1199) {
  .product { // you can write .product1, .product2,... but I would suggest creating this new class, as none of those images really need their own css
    max-width: 25%;  //this will change for tablet and mobile to 50% and 100%
  }
}
```

Now do that for all modes that you want.

Also note that instead of setting a `margin-right` you could use flexbox with `justify-content: space-between` in the wrapper; Otherwise you will have to remove those margins for different screen sizes.

Comment: Its not working. I need to have 2 products on a line and 2 more below those. So 2 lines with 2 products

Comment: I need to make those 4 products for tablet and phone like in those images I just posted. Sorry the images where not working.

Comment: I understand what you want, but you never said what doesn't work. I am not going to code for you.